# Failed to create index in OpenDJ 2.6.0

Tags: opendj

When I creating the indexes according to the [instructions](http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/12.0.0/install-guide/index/chap-prepare-install.html#prepare-configuration-store-indexes) in OpenDJ 2.6.0.

I encounter the following errors

```
$/opt/opendj/bin/dsconfig create-local-db-index --hostname 127.0.0.1 --port 4444 --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword 123 --backend-name cfgStore --index-name iplanet-am-user-federation-info-key --set index-type:equality --trustAll;

The Local DB Index could not be created because of the following reason:

    *  [LDAP: error code 53 - The Directory Server is unwilling to add
       configuration entry
       ds-cfg-attribute=iplanet-am-user-federation-info-key,cn=Index,ds-cfg-bac
       kend-id=cfgStore,cn=Backends,cn=config because one of the add listeners
       registered with the parent entry
       cn=Index,ds-cfg-backend-id=cfgStore,cn=Backends,cn=config rejected this
       change with the message: The Local DB Index could not be decoded due to
       the following reason: The string value
       "iplanet-am-user-federation-info-key" is not a valid value for the
       "attribute" property, which must have the following syntax: OID]


$/opt/opendj/bin/dsconfig create-local-db-index --hostname 127.0.0.1 --port 4444 --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword 123 --backend-name cfgStore --index-name sun-fm-saml2-nameid-infokey --set index-type:equality --trustAll;

The Local DB Index could not be created because of the following reason:

    *  [LDAP: error code 53 - The Directory Server is unwilling to add
       configuration entry
       ds-cfg-attribute=sun-fm-saml2-nameid-infokey,cn=Index,ds-cfg-backend-id=
       cfgStore,cn=Backends,cn=config because one of the add listeners
       registered with the parent entry
       cn=Index,ds-cfg-backend-id=cfgStore,cn=Backends,cn=config rejected this
       change with the message: The Local DB Index could not be decoded due to
       the following reason: The string value "sun-fm-saml2-nameid-infokey" is
       not a valid value for the "attribute" property, which must have the
       following syntax: OID]


$/opt/opendj/bin/dsconfig create-local-db-index --hostname 127.0.0.1 --port 4444 --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword 123 --backend-name cfgStore --index-name sunxmlkeyvalue --set index-type:equality --set index-type:substring --trustAll;

The Local DB Index could not be created because of the following reason:

    *  [LDAP: error code 53 - The Directory Server is unwilling to add
       configuration entry
       ds-cfg-attribute=sunxmlkeyvalue,cn=Index,ds-cfg-backend-id=cfgStore,cn=B
       ackends,cn=config because one of the add listeners registered with the
       parent entry cn=Index,ds-cfg-backend-id=cfgStore,cn=Backends,cn=config
       rejected this change with the message: The Local DB Index could not be
       decoded due to the following reason: The string value "sunxmlkeyvalue"
       is not a valid value for the "attribute" property, which must have the
       following syntax: OID]
```

Please what's wrong? how could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to create an index for an attribute that is not defined in the OpenDJ server's schema. The server cannot understand how to index it.
Please load OpenAM schema first.

Comment: I followed the instruction and created the schema before creating the index.`/opt/opendj/bin/ldapmodify --hostname 127.0.0.1 --port 4444 --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword 123 --defaultAdd --trustAll --useSSL --filename /cts-add-schema.ldif ;`  And I can see the schema after connecting to the LDAP